# Cannot import json file into Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a JSON file (from Mongo University) with some JSON in it

However, when I run the import:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin> .\mongoimport.exe -d blog -c posts --drop posts.json
```

I get an error and nothing is imported:

```
2016-04-15T22:21:27.771+0100    connected to: localhost
2016-04-15T22:21:27.772+0100    dropping: blog.posts
2016-04-15T22:21:28.635+0100    error inserting documents: lost connection to server
2016-04-15T22:21:28.635+0100    Failed: lost connection to server
2016-04-15T22:21:28.640+0100    imported 0 documents
```

From the server:

```
2016-04-15T22:21:22.070+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8860 port=27017 dbpath=F:\Mongo\ 64-bit host=Plod
2016-04-15T22:21:22.071+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Server 2003 SP2
2016-04-15T22:21:22.072+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.11
2016-04-15T22:21:22.072+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 48f8b49dc30cc2485c6c1f3db31b723258fcbf39
2016-04-15T22:21:22.072+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, pl
atform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-04-15T22:21:22.072+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-04-15T22:21:22.073+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "F:\Mongo\" } }
2016-04-15T22:21:22.079+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=F:\Mongo\journal
2016-04-15T22:21:22.079+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2016-04-15T22:21:22.117+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2016-04-15T22:21:22.118+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2016-04-15T22:21:22.234+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-04-15T22:21:27.770+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:5047 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-04-15T22:21:27.772+0100 I COMMAND  [conn1] CMD: drop blog.posts
2016-04-15T22:21:28.084+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:5048 #2 (2 connections now open)
2016-04-15T22:21:28.231+0100 I -        [conn2] Assertion: 10334:BSONObj size: 33609065 (0x200D569) is invalid. Size must be betwe
en 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "posts"
2016-04-15T22:21:28.610+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace_win.cpp(175)                       mon
go::printStackTrace+0x43
2016-04-15T22:21:28.611+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\log.cpp(134)                                  mon
go::logContext+0x8f
2016-04-15T22:21:28.611+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(219)                          mon
go::msgasserted+0xce
2016-04-15T22:21:28.611+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(211)                          mon
go::msgasserted+0x13
2016-04-15T22:21:28.612+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\bson\bsonobj.cpp(73)                               mon
go::BSONObj::_assertInvalid+0x40c
2016-04-15T22:21:28.612+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbmessage.cpp(131)                              mon
go::DbMessage::nextJsObj+0x1a0
2016-04-15T22:21:28.612+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbmessage.h(302)                                mon
go::QueryMessage::QueryMessage+0x6a
2016-04-15T22:21:28.613+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(194)                               mon
go::receivedQuery+0xbf
2016-04-15T22:21:28.613+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(377)                               mon
go::assembleResponse+0x2fd
2016-04-15T22:21:28.614+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(205)                                     mon
go::MyMessageHandler::process+0xb8
2016-04-15T22:21:28.614+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(232)              mon
go::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg+0x553
2016-04-15T22:21:28.614+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(185)  boo
st::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
2016-04-15T22:21:28.615+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\threadex.c(376)                 _ca
llthreadstartex+0x17
2016-04-15T22:21:28.622+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\threadex.c(354)                 _th
readstartex+0x102
2016-04-15T22:21:28.622+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2] KERNEL32.DLL                                                                   Bas
eThreadInitThunk+0x22
2016-04-15T22:21:28.629+0100 I CONTROL  [conn2]
2016-04-15T22:21:28.630+0100 I NETWORK  [conn2] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 10334 BSONObj size
: 33609065 (0x200D569) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "posts"
2016-04-15T22:21:28.642+0100 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:5047 (0 connections now open)
```

What's going on?

I've tried it with 3.0 and 3.2.

Comment: What does the data in the JSON file look like? Is everything wrapped in `[]`? Or does it look unreadable and therefore is more likely a BSON dump?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-939, there is a bug which is affecting some versions of `mongoimport` and `mongorestore` that causes your `mongoimport` command to fail.

To sort out this problem, you can use `--batchSize` option with argument as `1`.

Use this reformed query:

```
mongoimport -d blog -c posts < posts.json --batchSize 1
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -j or --numInsertionWorkers flag. Some version  has some  issues and ticket was created in past. https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/TOOLS-939

```
mongoimport -j 4 -d blog -c posts --drop posts.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following format

```
mongoimport posts.json -d blog -c posts --drop --jsonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

**To import json file to your currently working mongoDB batabase, please follow the steps given below.**

1. Go to your [the link](https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/5e97263c3c730b1f7e9db9c9#clusters) and then select the cluster that your currently working with.
2. Click on **COLLECTIONS** and after that go to **command line tools**.
3. You can see **Data Import and Export Tools** over there which provides the command to import your json file to your database.
4. Replace the tags as instructed in the command.

If you get any error like:

```
Failed: cannot decode array into a D
```

Then add --jsonArray at last of the command.
**Example:**

```
mongoimport --host <hostname> --ssl --username <username> --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --file <FILENAME> --jsonArray
```