# How to import json file content to mongodb as documents?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

Users.json file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "abc"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "pqr"
}
```

how to insert json data which comtains 50k documents in mongodb (as documents not array)

Comment: I hope, this might help those who get stuck. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657175/cannot-import-json-file-into-mongo/61437342#61437342](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657175/cannot-import-json-file-into-mongo/61437342#61437342)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mongo-shell mongoimport with below-given command

```
mongoimport --db databaseName --collection collectionName --drop --file ~/path/to/file/fileName.json
```

Comment: > mongoimport --db db144 --collection countries --drop --file ~E:/restReg/json.json
               2019-02-08T15:59:57.629+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14

Comment: @MrunallVeer Are you using mac or windows?

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: @MrunallVeer please try with removing '~' from the file path and give the absolute path of the file

Comment: Beware of `--drop`. If your json has errors and the command fails, the collection will still get dropped!

Answer (score -2):

You can copy the whole json then use insert() to insert one document in the respective collection.

Eg: Collection Name: users

```
db.getCollection('users').insert(
{
    "Users": [{
          "id": 1,
           "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
         "name": "pqr"
     )]
 })
```

In order to add multiple documents then use insertMany()

Eg:

```
db.getCollection('users').insertMany(
    [{
        "Users": [{
              "id": 1,
               "name": "abc"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
             "name": "pqr"
         )]
     },
     {
        "Users": [{
              "id": 3,
               "name": "abc"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
             "name": "pqr"
         )]
     }]
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
db.collection.insert(
   <document or array of documents>,
   {
     writeConcern: <document>,
     ordered: <boolean>
   }
)
```